# Is it possible to convert a JsonAttribute to an Integer

Tags: c#, nlog

Is it possible with Nlog in JsonLayout a JsonAttribute as Interger spend. The properties are always output as a string.
I have tried the following code example:

So far the edition is correct, just as a string and not a Ineger.

Can help me someone to understand what is wrong?

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("level", info => info.Level.Ordinal * 100);
var fieldsLayout = new JsonLayout
{
    RenderEmptyObject = false,
    SuppressSpaces = true
};

fieldsLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("channel", "${channel}"));
fieldsLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("level", "${level}"));
```

Comment: I don't know about the `${channel}` layout renderer, but for the log level, you might try `${level:format=Ordinal}`. I don't know whether it will really help, but doing this is easy enough to be worth a try at least...

Comment: Yes thats right. But i need the Ordinal Level * 100. Thanks dir YouTube andere.

Comment: The Ordinal Levels only 1,2,3, ....
But i need the level as 100, 200, 300

Comment: Then create a custom layout renderer and use it in place of the `${level}` layout renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it is a bad idea to override the default `${level}` renderer.

The easy solution for level is just doing this:

```
fieldsLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("level", "${level:format=ordinal}") { Encode = false });
```

But if you need to have it multiplied by 100 then you need to register a custom layout renderer:

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("level100", info => info.Level.Ordinal * 100);
fieldsLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("level", "${level100}") { Encode = false });
```

Comment: Ok. I think the same about override default layout renderer. I follow your hint and it works. Thank a lot